# UIActivityViewController Hide More from Actions

Tags: ios, swift, uiactivityviewcontroller

When I initialize the UIActivityViewController and disable all actions, I still see a More button under the actions bar. Is there a way to remove it?

[image: UIActivityViewController More Button]

This is how I initialize it:

```
let activityVC = UIActivityViewController(activityItems: objectsToShare, applicationActivities: nil)
activityVC.excludedActivityTypes = [UIActivityTypeAirDrop, UIActivityTypeAddToReadingList,UIActivityTypeCopyToPasteboard,UIActivityTypeSaveToCameraRoll,UIActivityTypePrint,UIActivityTypeAssignToContact,UIActivityTypeCopyToPasteboard]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, this is the button where the user choose to enable app extensions, and you are not allowed to hide extension the user chose to display